# Oracle PLSQL: insert ID that is in sequence of one table into another

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger that whenever you insert values inside a table called `hotel`, it takes some values from the field and inserts it inside another table called `Restaurant`.

My `Hotel_ID` is in sequence so I don't really give its value when I am using the insert statement to insert values inside the hotel table. Which creates problems for the restaurant table as it sets the value of `Hotel_ID` to null. I know in the insert statement I can just add the sequence name so that it works but the thing is, later on I have to convert my tables into APEX forms and with them, you can't insert the ID at all.

Anyway, here is my trigger that is basically supposed to take values from some fields of `Hotel` table and insert them into the Restaurant table:-

```
create or replace TRIGGER HOTELREST BEFORE INSERT ON HOTEL 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        INSERT INTO RESTAURANT(CITY,ADDRESS,HOTEL_ID)
        VALUES (:NEW.CITY,:NEW.ADDRESS,:NEW.HOTEL_ID);
    END IF;
END;
```

Although the values of `City` and `address` get inserted inside the `restaurant` table, the value of `hotel_id` doesn't. Here is my insert statement for `hotel`:

```
INSERT INTO HOTEL(NAME,CITY,COUNTRY,ADDRESS,RATINGS) 
VALUES ('Westin','Manchester','UK',5);
```

Now again, before you say that I didn't give an Id of the hotel, like I said, I am using sequence so when this row gets inserted inside the `hotel` table, a value for `Hotel_Id` is automatically generated. My trigger is also supposed to add `Hotel_Id` in my `Restaurant` table but it doesn't. It remains null. What do I do?

Comment: If your trigger is `AFTER INSERT` rather than `BEFORE INSERT`?

Comment: How are you setting the hotel ID - do you already have a before-insert trigger on this table? You can merge them into one; or make this one after-insert?

Comment: @Glenn  Damn I am an idiot. Ofc.. Had to use After.. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks! figured out I need to use After